# Cocos2d-x 3.0: is there any other way to move on previous screen?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am new in cocos2d-x and i am using 3.0beta sdk. 
I am using below code to navigate from one screen to another and vice-versa.

```
 Director *pDirector = Director::getInstance();
 pDirector->replaceScene(nextscreen);
```

Do you know, how can we move on previous screen via other ways? I think, this is creating a cycle of Scenes.

Thanks
Kamal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing scene is a good idea since it destroys previous, freeing the memory.
However you can also use pushScene()/popScene() methods to move between scenes.

Comment: Suspends the execution of the running scene, pushing it on the stack of suspended scenes.

The new scene will be executed. Try to avoid big stacks of pushed scenes to reduce memory allocation. ONLY call it if there is a running scene.